# Why is git pages rendering my page different then in local?

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm rather new to whole react thing, going through courses on FCC. My problem come from CSS/SCSS itself. I tried ordinary CSS and SCSS. My page is done in React. The page is also hosted on codepen. All three versions are the same, codepen, git and local and yet CSS is somewhat different between them. My previous projects who are also hosted on these platforms and in local have also the same CSS but they look identical. Difference between local and codepen's version isn't that drastic, but between local>codepen>github is more than noticeable as you descend. Do GitHub ignores/renders? or what, React differently? This question should also apply to codepen.

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/codename11/full/vaqMwE/)

My [git page](https://codename11.github.io/markdown_previewer/)

My [repoToProject](https://github.com/codename11/markdown_previewer)

Image of localhost: [image]

html from codepen:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

scss from codepen:

```
    $position: absolute;
$percentage: 100%;
$color: whitesmoke;
$car: auto;

@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

.btn1 {
  position: $position;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 51.3%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: $color;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  color: aqua;
}

#root {
  width: $percentage;
}

body,
html {
  height: $percentage;
}

body {
  background-color: $color;
  background-image: url("../images/react1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: $car;
  background-position: center bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  background-color: $color;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  width: $percentage;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 25px 98%;
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
}

#inner2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #d6e9c6;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  width: $percentage;
  margin-left: $car;
  margin-right: $car;
  position: $position;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: $percentage;
  min-height: 20%;
  max-height: $percentage;
}

#editor {
  width: $percentage;
  background-color: white;
  resize: none;
  color: #495057;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  overflow-y: $car;
  max-height: $percentage;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#preview {
  width: 98.9%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  overflow-y: $car;
  max-height: $percentage;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#item1,
#item2 {
  font-family: "Russo One";
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: $percentage;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.insignia {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: letter-spacing 1s;
  transition: letter-spacing 1s;
}

.insignia:hover {
  letter-spacing: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-resizable-s {
  cursor: row-resize;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#arrow {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  width: $percentage;
  height: 15px;
  position: $position;
  bottom: -12px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  text-align: center;
}

.glyphicon {
  top: -4px;
  left: 4px;
  color: gray;
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 0.6); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0.6); /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1, 0.6);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  #inner2 {
    height: 90vh !important;
  }
}

#eraser {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin-left: $car;
  margin-right: $car;
}

/*Additional styling*/

td,
th {
  border: 2px solid #224b4b;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.label {
  position: $position;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: $percentage;
  z-index: 999;
}

.preview-editor {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: $percentage;
  height: $percentage;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #224b4b;
}

h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #224b4b;
}

code {
  background-color: #d6e9c6;
  color: #e83e8c !important;
}

blockquote {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #ggED {
    text-align: left;
  }

  #ggPrev {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .insignia,
  .insignia:hover {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

js from codepen:

```
var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
renderer.link = function(href, title, text) {
  return (
    '<a target="_blank" href="' +
    href +
    '" title="' +
    title +
    '">' +
    text +
    "</a>"
  );
};

marked.setOptions({
  breaks: true,
  renderer: renderer,
  sanitize: true
});

class DisplayMessages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markdown: defaultMarkdown,
      erase: false,
      goFull: false,
      headViewKlasa: "grid-item",
      headEdKlasa: "grid-item",
      editorKlasa: "",
      previewKlasa: "",
      stilPreview: {},
      stilEditor: {},
      attr: "Click on me for fullscreen",
      inner2H: "",
      h2Inner: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.eraseFields = this.eraseFields.bind(this);
    this.inner2Height = this.inner2Height.bind(this);
  }

  eraseFields() {
    this.setState({
      erase: true
    });

    if (this.state.erase === false) {
      this.setState({
        markdown: ""
      });
    }

    if (this.state.erase === true) {
      this.setState({
        markdown: defaultMarkdown,
        erase: !this.state.erase
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    $(this.node).resizable({
      handles: "s",
      minHeight: 170
    });

    document
      .querySelector(".ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s")
      .setAttribute(
        "title",
        "Double click on me or pull me down to full height"
      );
  }

  inner2Height() {
    if (this.state.h2Inner === false) {
      this.setState({
        inner2H: "100%",
        h2Inner: true
      });
    }

    if (this.state.h2Inner === true) {
      this.setState({
        inner2H: "",
        h2Inner: false
      });
    }
  }

  fullScreen(clicked_id) {
    if (clicked_id === "ggEd" && this.state.goFull === false) {
      this.setState({
        headEdKlasa: this.state.headEdKlasa + " label",
        attr: "Click again to go back!",
        editorKlasa: "preview-editor",
        stilPreview: { display: "none" },
        stilEditor: { paddingTop: "0px" },
        goFull: true
      });
    }

    if (clicked_id === "ggEd" && this.state.goFull === true) {
      this.setState({
        headEdKlasa: this.state.headEdKlasa.substr(0, 9),
        attr: "Click on me for fullscreen",
        editorKlasa: "",
        stilPreview: { display: "block" },
        stilEditor: { paddingTop: "10px" },
        goFull: !this.state.goFull
      });
    }

    if (clicked_id === "ggPrev" && this.state.goFull === false) {
      this.setState({
        headViewKlasa: this.state.headViewKlasa + " label",
        attr: "Click again to go back!",
        previewKlasa: "preview-editor",
        stilEditor: { display: "none" },
        stilPreview: { paddingTop: "0px" },
        goFull: true
      });
    }

    if (clicked_id === "ggPrev" && this.state.goFull === true) {
      this.setState({
        headViewKlasa: this.state.headViewKlasa.substr(0, 9),
        attr: "Click on me for fullscreen",
        previewKlasa: "",
        stilEditor: { display: "block" },
        stilPreview: { paddingTop: "10px" },
        goFull: !this.state.goFull
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      markdown: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const btnText = this.state.erase ? "Populate" : "Erase";
    const handleClick = e => this.fullScreen(e.target.id);
    return (
      <div
        id="inner2"
        className="grid-container animated zoomIn"
        style={{ height: this.state.inner2H }}
        onDoubleClick={this.inner2Height}
      >
        <EditorHead
          id={"item1"}
          style={this.state.stilEditor}
          className={this.state.headEdKlasa}
          onClick={handleClick}
          title={this.state.attr}
        />

        <PreviewHead
          id={"item2"}
          style={this.state.stilPreview}
          className={this.state.headViewKlasa}
          onClick={handleClick}
          title={this.state.attr}
        />

        <BtnEraser
          id={"eraser"}
          onClick={this.eraseFields}
          type={"button"}
          className={"btn btn-danger btn-lg"}
          title={"Erase & populate both fields"}
          value={btnText}
        />

        <Editor
          id={"editor"}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className={this.state.editorKlasa}
          value={this.state.markdown}
          placeholder={"Enter ... some kind a text!? ..."}
          title={
            "This is rather obvious isn't it? It's editor window Sherlock :D"
          }
        />

        <Preview
          id={"preview"}
          className={this.state.previewKlasa}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: marked(this.state.markdown, { renderer: renderer })
          }}
          title={"It's a preview window, Sherlock ;)"}
        />

        <Arrow id={"arrow"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/*class Inner2 extends React.Component{

    render(){ 
        return (
            <div id={this.props.id} className={this.props.className} style={this.props.style} onDoubleClick={this.props.onDoubleClick}>Editor:</div>
        );  
    }
}*/

class EditorHead extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1
        id={this.props.id}
        style={this.props.style}
        className={this.props.className}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        <span className="insignia" title={this.props.title} id="ggEd">
          Editor:
        </span>
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

class PreviewHead extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1
        id={this.props.id}
        style={this.props.style}
        className={this.props.className}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        <span className="insignia" title={this.props.title} id="ggPrev">
          Previewer:
        </span>
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

class BtnEraser extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        id={this.props.id}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        type={this.props.type}
        className={this.props.className}
        title={this.props.title}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Editor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <textarea
        id={this.props.id}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        className={this.props.className}
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        title={this.props.title}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Preview extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id={this.props.id}
        className={this.props.className}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML}
        title={this.props.title}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Arrow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id={this.props.id}>
        <Glyph className={"glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Glyph extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span className={this.props.className} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DisplayMessages />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Can you be specific, like what changes are there between local version and Github pages version?

Comment: @Dane None, code is exactly the same. Only difference is Codepen where you can't divide React components into separate files to import them, so i just put them after main component.

Comment: In local, you use webpack to bundle all the different files into a single js file. In Codepen, there is no webpack and, you cannot have different files, all JS code should be written in that single box, so you do it. If there is some unexpected output change between them, then it's a problem. Otherwise this is the way. If you're using `create-react-app` if you run `npm run build` you can see a `main.js` file generated. So basically it's always one js file that is included in your HTML, all the time. Getting?

Comment: @Dane Ok, i found them. What now? Ps: I'm learning, as you stated, by using npm.

Comment: I still don't get what is your problem. What do you want to do? What is your expected output??

Comment: @Dane As i stated, css is same across all of three of them. Problem is that they have small differences in rendering. For example: padding-top: 10px; looks different like isn't applied on git,  on local looks applied, on codepen looks like 5px ... Similar things is with font size, font-size: 2em doesn't look like 2em on git ... Small inconsistencies in css but they add up. Open side by side git, codepen and image and you'll see the difference. But code is the same.

Comment: That might be something you can figure out using the Devtools. See what styles are getting applied. Maybe difference in order of styles being applied, or versions of bootstrap, etc. As a learner, you have to do it yourself :)

Comment: @Dane I'm using 'inspect' and all styles/classes are applied, but when rendered they look different. I also checked main.js and main.css in after building/deploying to github/pages. They look same, used search in my code editor since it's minified, but didn't find any difference between styles built for gitpages and ones that are not i.e. non minified.

Comment: @Dane is it because in local is automatically is set in dev mode but in git is in prod mode? Still that doesn't explain difference in rendering since i checked by using inspect and it shows same styling on both local/dev and git/prod.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178832/discussion-between-dane-and-veljko-stefanovic).